# WordPress, Themosis Framework , Mac OS X , MAMP - How to setup ?

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I have installed themosis framework for wordpress for MAMP but I unfortunately cannot start the wordpress installation and instead I get a directory listing when I access the url.

I have created a vhosts for MAMP and still I am getting the same directory listing.

Does anyone out there know what can be done to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The list (the url is most likely localhost) should have a link that says "wordpress" (or whatever you renamed the folder with all WordPress content) click on that link, and you should be redirected to a configuration page.

Comment: The url is "http://localhost:8888/themosis" and the directory listing is :

Index of /themosis

Parent Directory
.env.local
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.travis.yml
README.md
bootstrap/
composer.json
composer.lock
config/
htdocs/
library/
log/
phpunit.xml
storage/
tests/
vendor/
wp-cli.yml

I cannot access the htdocs folder ..it gives 404 error

Comment: Check your computer files to see if it's missing, if not copy the folder then delete it, and paste it in again.